# How to update records "unrelated" to current graph?

Tags: acumatica

I am not sure if i have just forgotten how to go about this or whether i havent had to do it before....

I have a new custom page with new tables and graph associated with it. It works fine for maintaining this custom data.  I have an action that needs to update a custom field in INItemLotSerial (note this does not have a graph associated with it).  Normally, i have created an instance of the corresponding graph and done updates using that instance.

I just need to do the equivalent of update INItemLotSerial set usr1 = 'test' where InventoryID = x and LotSerialNbr = y

I am unsure how to approach this? i was thinking i could select the record into an instance of the DAC and update the values, but i do not know how to commit that back to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

1. you need view. Let's say you made view like this:
   `public PXSelect<PMTask> PMTasksSelect;`
2. you read your object in some way
   `PMTask pm = PMTasksSelect.Select(Base).FirstOrDefault();`
3. Inform cache of Acumatica that you changed object:
   `PMTasksSelect.Cache.SetValueExt(pm, "RateTableID", "A");`
   `PMTasksSelect.Cache.SetStatus(task2, PXEntryStatus.Modified);`
   `PMTasksSelect.Cache.IsDirty = true;`
4. Finally you can persist your changes to db:

   `PMTasksSelect.Cache.Update(taskExt);`

Comment: I will try both approaches suggested - this one is different than i usually do, so i would like to see if i can make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a view related to the DAC you want to update. So in this case, you can define a view for the DAC like

```
public PXSelect<INItemLotSerial, Where<INItemLotSerial.inventoryID, Equal<Current<YourField>>,
                                        And<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr, Equal<Current<YourField>>>>> LotSerialInfo;
```

So this view will cache the record you want to update. Now you can update the record anytime like

```
INItemLotSerial rec = LotSerialInfo.Current as INItemLotSerial;
//Get extension if you want
recExt.YourExtField = "something";
LotSerialInfo.Update(rec);
```

The persist of your graph will save the information you Inserted/Updated/Deleted.

Hope It gives you the idea and helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, i started down this path and talked myself out of it, i will take it all the way to completion and see how it goes - thanks!